# How troubleshoot ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure?

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob, knowrobtutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I Follow: Knowledge Processing For Autonomous Robot

I write a simple knowledge base as a test.pl in prolog file, in my package then I try to query it

```
prolog -f test.pl
```

and I get a top level error !

```
?- cup(cup0).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: cup/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

**Edit**

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ prolog -f test.pl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 5.10.4)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- cup(cup0).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: cup/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
?-
```

and that is what in test.pl

```
cup(cup0).
dairyProduct(milk1).
meatProduct(ham2).
cupboard(cupboard3).
refrigerator(fridge4).
perishable(Prod)            :- dairyProduct(Prod), meatProduct(Prod).
storagePlaceFor(Loc, Item)  :- refrigerator(Loc), perishable(Item).
storagePlaceFor(Loc, Item)  :- cupboard(Loc), cup(Item).
searchForIn(Item,Loc)       :- storagePlaceFor(Loc, Item).
```

any suggestion ?!

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54124/how-troubleshoot-error:-toplevel:-undefined-procedure-?!/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not related to KnowRob but a problem with Prolog or your test files. You'll need to check if test.pl contains the correct predicate definitions, no syntax errors (did you get any error messages when starting Prolog?) and if the lines with definitions of e.g. cup(cup0) start with :-

**EDIT**
When I just copy/paste your file and try it, it works for me. System configuration seems to be the same, maybe you need to check why the first output line seems to be missing in your case (..compiled...)

```
tenorth@lapradig6:~$ prolog -f test.pl 
% [...]/test.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 4,112 bytes
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 5.10.4)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- cup(cup0).
true.
```

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-17**:
I edit my Q

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-18**:
I am still do not get what I have to do now !
Thanks